# Calculating Betti numbers of torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, betti-numbers

I'm beginning to study some algebraic topology and I'm having some trouble working out the example of the torus.  I want to calculate its Betti numbers, which are described as the "$k$-dimensional holes" of a surface.  The rigorous definition is the rank of the homology groups $H_n$.  So if I want to calculate $\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2$, then the approaches I can think of are either trying to do it from the former intuitive definition rigorously, or find a triangulation of the torus and calculate it by hand.

I can't figure either of these out.  I can't tell if I'm missing something or if a triangulation of the torus is nontrivial, but the fact that the intuitive answer seems so simple suggests to me there should be a simpler way (as opposed to finding a complicated triangulation) to calculate them rigorously, either by making the intuition rigorous or by some other method.  I've also read that the Poincare polynomial somehow gives the Betti numbers for $T^n$ by $(1+x)^n$; does there underly an alternative approach here which might be simpler?

Comment: Perhaps, calculate the Betti numbers of $S^{1}$ and the use the Kunneth formula?  Although computing using a triangulation is a good exercise to understand the concept of homology which you should aim to do at some point (in my opinion).

Comment: Notice that the torus is $T^2=S^1\times S^1$, and in the way that $S^1\cong [0,1]/\{0,1\}$, you can get a pretty nice picture as a square with each pair of opposing sides identified, and write down an explicit triangulation without too much difficulty.

Comment: You might also notice that $T^2=S^1\times S^1$ is connected, so $b_0=1$. Moreover it is a 2-dimensional manifold, so Poincare duality gives $b_2=b_0=1$. Now you can calculate the Euler characteristic of a product by $\chi(X\times Y)=\chi(X)\cdot\chi(Y)$, which tells us that $\chi(S^1\times S^1)=\chi(S^1)^2=0$. However by definition $\chi(S^1\times S^1)=b_0-b_1+b_2=2b_0-b_1$. Hence $b_1=2b_0=2$.